# Big and public family tree as gedcom

Tags: family-tree, gedcom

Are there any public and big family trees available online as downloadable gedcom files?

Something like royal families, presidents or like that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're looking for big family trees of royal families, presidents, etc. in GEDCOM format, my favorite site is [Famous Family Trees](http://famousfamilytrees.blogspot.ca/) by Paul Pruitt.

Paul has all sorts of neat trees, many which he created or contracted for, including:

- [Genealogies of US Presidents](http://famousfamilytrees.blogspot.ca/2011/12/httpgenealogyoflife.html) all in one tree, and separate trees of Lincoln, Kennedy or George Washington
- [Royal Family Trees](http://famousfamilytrees.blogspot.ca/2008/07/royalty-family-trees-ged-files.html) including English, Irish, Greek, the Byzantine Empire, Mohammad, Cleopatra, Japanese, Chinese, India, Hawaii
- [Religious Trees](http://famousfamilytrees.blogspot.ca/2008/07/links-to-religious-system-ged-file.html) - the Bible, Gods of various cultures, and more Mohammad
- [Trees of Famous People](http://famousfamilytrees.blogspot.ca/2008/07/famous-artists-intellectuals-and.html) including Bach, Shakespeare, Ghandi, Keynes

The main purpose for his site is to house Paul's [Catalog of Life Database](http://famousfamilytrees.blogspot.ca/2008/07/species-family-trees.html), which includes 1,257,735 different living species that inhabit the world. I believe this is the largest meaningful GEDCOM ever created and it includes 2.1 million individuals. It is 650,134 KB in size.

The site also has interesting GEDCOMs for [a few fictional family trees](http://famousfamilytrees.blogspot.ca/2008/07/fictional-family-trees.html) (Harry Potter, Lord of the Rings, the Simpsons), a couple dozen [Corporate Family Trees](http://famousfamilytrees.blogspot.ca/2008/07/corporate-family-trees.html) (including General Electric, Walt Disney, Apple and others), [Genetic Haplotypes](http://famousfamilytrees.blogspot.ca/2011/12/genetic-haplotypes-as-gedcom-trees.html), [the Structure of the US Government](http://famousfamilytrees.blogspot.ca/2011/12/structure-of-us-government-as-gedcom.html), [a family tree of Human and Computer Languages](http://famousfamilytrees.blogspot.ca/2011/12/making-family-tree-of-human-and.html), and the [Microsoft Operating System Version History](http://famousfamilytrees.blogspot.ca/2011/12/microsoft-operating-system-version.html).

---

Update Nov 1, 2022:

As Jeremy Jones noted in his comment, it appears that the website genealogyoflife.com is no longer active. That is where all the GEDCOMs I mentioned were stored.

However, it does appear that many of the GEDCOMs were saved by the Internet Archive. You can find a listing of the ones available here: https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://genealogyoflife.com/tng/gedcom/*

Comment: None of those links work in 2022.

Answer (score 6):

[Tamura Jones](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/users/20/tamurajones) has a gedcom generator "GedFan" that can be used for testing purposes. A blog describing latest version is at [2015-03-18 GedFan 0.4.0.0](http://www.tamurajones.net/GedFan0.4.0.0.xhtml) See the links section at the bottom of that page for other resources.

Although each individual is bare-bones, the number of individuals is determined by the number of generations specified.

Answer (score 4):

I use a GEDcom from this source: [Thomas Stobie's Genealogy Pages](http://freepages.genealogy.rootsweb.ancestry.com/~stobie/index.htm) for testing high-volume imports -- no famous people, but it's public and big ("640,000+ people")...