# Where to find "real" GEDCOM files to test computer softeware?

Tags: gedcom, sources

I am aware this is a repetition of [this 2015 question](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/8004/big-and-public-family-tree-as-gedcom/19256?noredirect=1#comment28751_19256), but it is 8 years old now, and the answers are no longer valid. I am in a software project of which one of the components has to operate with GEDCOM data. I am looking for any reasonable GEDCOM files (no British royalty and no Norse gods) to be used as test material.

The links given in the answers to the 2015 question are more or less all dead, the files given in the Wayback machine are no GEDCOM (despite *.ged as extension).

The files can be, of course, anonymized.

Comment: This comes from the Meta of another SE site but I think it represents your [Options when question is duplicate of one with no/inadequate/old answers](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4011/115).

Comment: This question should not be closed as the OP states that the links in that post are no longer valid so asks a valid question. In answer to the question there are several large trees available at https://sourceforge.net/projects/godskingsheroes/ and several of these could be concatenated to make even larger trees for testing purposes.

Comment: @Colin Thanks for support. To obtain test data is a real problem, and the 2015 discussion does not give any satisfactory guidance. Besides, I mentioned the anonymized option, so, technically, it is a new question.

Comment: The 2015 question may be old and the links in its answers may be dead, but that's no reason to create what is basically a duplicate. New answers can be added to that existing question.

Comment: If it’s open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: @PolyGeo Thanks! I will look there!